# js not working on IE but working on FF.....giving inner.html error..so want to convert in jquery format

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser

Why this javascript working fine in Firefox but not in IE 6 and 7 ( haven't checked on IE8)?

giving inner.html error. **Can any jquery expert convert this whole code into jquery?** as i'm already using jquery on same site for other things.

```
function twoDecPlaces(theValue) {
var nm = new Number( Math.round( theValue * 100 ) ) /100 ;
 var parts = nm.toString().split( '.' );
 var ord = new Number( parts[ 0 ] );
 var dec = ( parts[ 1 ] ) ? parts[ 1 ] : '';
 if( dec ){
  dec = dec.toString().substring( 0, 2 );
  ord += '.' + dec;
 }

 return( ord );

}

function fourDecPlaces(theValue) {
num = theValue;
result = num.toFixed(4); 

 return( result );

}

function isNumber(val)
{
 if (isNaN(val))
 {
  return false;
 }
 if (val==0)
 {
  return false;
 }
 else
 {
  return true;
 } 
}


function doCalc()
{
 if (isNumber(document.getElementById("num_shares").value))
 {
  var dividend_rate = document.getElementById('dividend_rate');
  var currency = document.getElementById('currency').value;
  var dividendValue = dividend_rate.options[dividend_rate.selectedIndex].value;
  var num_shares = document.getElementById('num_shares');

  num_shares = parseInt(num_shares.value);

  var totalDividend = dividendValue * num_shares;
  var valuePaid = document.getElementById('valuePaid');
  var divpershare = document.getElementById('divpershare');

  divpersharevalue = fourDecPlaces(dividendValue/1000);
  divpersharevalue = divpersharevalue + "&nbsp;" + currency;

  totalDividend = twoDecPlaces(totalDividend/100);
  totalDividend = totalDividend + "&nbsp;" + currency;

     valuePaid.style.display="";
  divpershare.style.display="";
  valuePaid.innerHTML = "<td>The total dividend paid was:</td><td align='right'>"+totalDividend+"</td>";
  divpershare.innerHTML = "<td>The dividend per share was:</td><td align='right'>"+divpersharevalue+"</td>";
 }
else
 {
  alert("Invalid entry in dividend box");
  document.getElementById("num_shares").value="";
  document.getElementById('valuePaid').innerHTML=""; 
 }
}
```

**Can any jquery expert convert this whole code into jquery?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some things I noticed:

- I'm not sure why you are using two different methods, one for`twoDecPlaces` and another for the `fourDecPlaces` function.
- You shouldn't need to insert table cells with data to display results. I would just have the text in place in the table (but hidden), so then you only need to update the value.

This is how I would modify the result table (CSS included):

```
<style type="text/css">
.text, .val { display: none; }
</style>
<table>
<tr id="valuePaid"><td class="text">The total dividend paid was:</td><td class="val"></td></tr>
<tr id="divpershare"><td class="text">The dividend per share was:</td><td class="val"></td></tr>
</table>
```

And this would be your script made to work with the above HTMl. It's been cleaned up and jQuerified :)

```
function twoDecPlaces(theValue) {
 return theValue.toFixed(2);
}
function fourDecPlaces(theValue) {
 return theValue.toFixed(4);
}
function isNumber(val) {
 if (isNaN(val) || val == 0) { return false; }
 return true;
}
function doCalc(){
 if (isNumber($('#num_shares').val())) {
  var currency = $('#currency').val();
  var dividendValue = $('#dividend_rate').val();
  var num_shares = parseInt($('#num_shares').val(),10);
  var divpersharevalue = fourDecPlaces(dividendValue/1000) + "&nbsp;" + currency;
  var totalDividend = twoDecPlaces((dividendValue * num_shares)/100) + "&nbsp;" + currency;
  $('#valuePaid').find('.val').html(totalDividend);
  $('#divpershare').find('.val').html(divpersharevalue);
  $('.text, .val').show();
 } else {
  alert("Invalid entry in dividend box");
  $('#num_shares').val('');
  $('.text').hide();
  $('.val').empty();
 }
}
```

If you want to limit the input box to only allow numbers to be typed inside of it, there are several jQuery plugins available. Here is one called [Numeric](http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/numeric/).

Comment: ok two things need to be changed. 1) Don't put the functions above inside of the `$(document).ready(funtion(){...})` and 2) remove the `style="display:none;"` from both of your output rows and oops 3) Remove the extra equal sign from the `isNumber` function... I used three, but that won't work when the zero is text. Here is the updated jsbin (http://jsbin.com/ecesa/4)

Comment: ok it's working but this page http://jsbin.com/ecesa/4 giving js error on IE see here http://shup.com/Shup/289060/1102151126-My-Desktop.png

Comment: That's just a jsbin code error,  if you run the code outside of jsbin it works fine. Or if you want it to work in jsbin, just add this line to the HTML body and the error will go away `<p id="hello"></p>`

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer is very bad at editing the innerHTML of `table`, `thead`, `tbody`, and `tr` elements.

Either use standard DOM, replace the entire table, or replace the contents of indivdual cells.